# Divide 20 million data in Mysql to batches. Please suggest a faster approach?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, inner-join, large-data

I have a database table user_data with total rows of 20 million. It is basically the address data of users. A user can have multiple addresses. The user_id is in string format.

I need to divide the 20 million data into say 10 batches and update the corresponding batch_no against each row. User with same user_id should be in the same batch.

For which I am using php script and update join query(the field used for joining is of format varchar). Now it is taking around 60-70 minutes for updating 20 million rows. The user_id column is of type varchar(255) and is indexed.

Any help to make the process faster will be much appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) from user_data WHERE set=1";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':set'=> $this->set]);
$totalUserCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$limit = intval($totalUserCount/10);
$lastRecords = $totalUserCount%10;
$limit = $lastRecords > 0 ? $limit + 1 : $limit;
$lastOffset = false;

for($i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{
            $offset =  $limit * $i;

            if($lastOffset)
                $offset = ($limit * $i) + $lastRecords;
    
            $query = "UPDATE user_data t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct user_id FROM user_data 
                      WHERE set=1 LIMIT :offset, :limit) AS t2 
                      ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.set =1) 
                      SET batch_no=:batch_no";

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $batchNo = ($i+1);
            $stmt->bindParam(':batch_no',$batchNo,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':set',1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':offset',$offset,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':limit',$limit,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($lastRecords==($i+1)){
                $limit--; 
                $lastOffset = true;                    
            }
}
```

Table structure and sample data

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user_data`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `set_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `batch_no` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `user_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_data`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

| id(int) | user_id(varchar(255) | address_1 | address_2 | set_no | batch_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCDEFGH001 | street 12 | north avenue | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | ABCDEFGH001 | street 13 | north avenue | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | ABCDEFGH001 | street 14 | north avenue | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | GDJFDHFH004 | lane 13 | south avenue | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | HHSYEEEY002 | DF-01 | alabama | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | HHSYEEEY002 | GH-15 | central alabama | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | TETYEJEE056 | AKSH - 56 | north carolina | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Do you care what is used to split up the rows?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table?  Do you need to add a new column with `batch_no` or are you creating 10 tables or 10 files?  What will you do with each batch?

Comment: @RickJames, The primary column is 'id'. Sorry it wasn't updated properly earlier. The user_id column needs to be considered for spiting up the batches. Yes need to have a new column 'batch_no' which needs to be updated with the batch_no, so that each batch can be separately picked up from the same table with batch_no for processing.

Comment: Will `batch_no` be used more than once?  If not, it would be much faster to simply compute the batch_no as the csv files are being created.  That is, the `UPDATE` is very costly, especially if it won't be used more than once.

Comment: @RickJames, I have to only create a script that will divide the full data into batches at the best time possible. There is another system which will fetch the data by batch_no and process it. Please let me know if there is anything that can be done to improve the performance.

Comment: The `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000,1` trick in the link is the main trick for _efficient_ chunking.  The 1 `id` returned by that provides a boundary for one chunk.  Repeat that to get all the chunk boundaries.  Start a new question about chunking if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: Oops, I may not have provided the link:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig , especially the section on chunking.

Answer (score 0):

This is really comments - but space limited there.

You are talking about database performance but provided NO DETAILS of the table / index structures and no explain plans.

> I need to divide the 20 million data into say 10 batches and update the corresponding batch_no against each row

This sounds like something you would only do once - so why the requirement to make it go faster?

Why are you trying to split the data into 10 batches? What will the batches be used for?

I don't see anywhere in your code where you assign a value for `$batchno`

This looks like the XY problem.

Assuming that user_data.migration_batch is a nominal value and user_id is implemented as an integer sequence without repeating gaps you can achieve the same result (but the result itself is of very dubious value) much more quickly by simply running:

```
UPDATE user_data 
SET migration_batch=MOD(user_id, 10);
```

(but note that this does not address the performance problems which will arise when you actually start using the batch number for anything).

Given the simple functional mapping created betweed user_id and migration_batch.....do you even need to bother storing migration_batch in the database?

Comment: symcbean, Sorry, it was not migration_batch. It was batch_no. I have corrected it. The requirement was to split the data into 10 batches and export it to 10 csv files.
batch_no is set here "$batchNo = ($i+1);" in code. The MOD function in this query "UPDATE user_data 
SET migration_batch=MOD(user_id, 10);"  only works with integer, double etc. Here the user_id type is of string type.

Comment: "and export it to 10 csv files" - on a Linux/POSIX system, mysqldump and split will handle this (but potential issues with date formatting and blobs)

Comment: The export of data based on batches is done by other system which will fetch the data based on batch_no. I have to just divide this into 10 batches. But dividing it into batches is taking whole lot of time. I have to reduce the time taken.